# What does the FROM clause do in this Hive SQL?

Tags: hiveql

The following is from an [explanation](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65227/hive-explode-lateral-view-clarification.html) of lateral views:

```
select tf1.*, tf2.*
  from (select 0) t
  lateral view explode(map('A',10,'B',20,'C',30)) tf1
  lateral view explode(map('A',10,'B',20,'C',30)) tf2;
```

I understand the output:

```
tf1.key tf1.value   tf2.key tf2.value
A   10  A   10
B   20  B   20
C   30  C   30...
```

but I am not sure what

```
(select 0) t
```

is for. I think 
(select 0) is to to produce output even when null values are produced but what is the point of t?
It seems to work fine when this is removed completely.
Can I use t to refer to the fields? Why is select 0 in brackets: is this because this means there is always something produced, if so why is it not in the output?

Comment: "It seems to work fine when this is removed completely." - in Hive 1.2 it does not work. Your query is doing Cartesian join: 1 row x 3 rows x 3 rows = 9 rows

Comment: Thanks but why not just do 3 x 3?